# Issue while calling a stored procedure inside another stored procedure in while loop

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am calling a stored procedure in a loop in another stored procedure, But Inner SP runs only the first time. No error is shown there, I can't seem to find the reason, Any help would be highly appreciated

```sql
DELIMITER $$

USE `xxx_db`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `wrapper`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `wrapper`(p_StartPeriod DATE, p_EndPeriod DATE)
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE v_startperiod DATE;
    DECLARE v_endperiod DATE;
    DECLARE v_nextdate DATE;
    SET v_startperiod = p_StartPeriod;
    SET v_endperiod = p_EndPeriod;
    
    
    SET @TempStart = v_startperiod;
WHILE (@TempStart < v_endperiod) DO
    SET v_nextdate = DATE_ADD(@TempStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    call innersp(@TempStart,v_nextdate);
    SET @TempStart = DATE_ADD(@TempStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
END WHILE;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

In this code, The date arguments are passed to the inner SP, if a date range is given, Inner SP runs only for the first date coming in loop. Please help me to find the issue. The inner SP works fine when it is called alone, It inserts data into a table, but since the number of rows are huge I want to insert on a per day basis, instead of doing the complete date range. It's arguments are dates. That is why I wrote a wrapper SP to call this inner SP giving arguments per day for the complete date range.

Comment: You might be completely overthinking this, but can you also post what the SP is for "Innersp".  Might be an easier way to do what you are attempting.  And edit your existing post, dont just comment with its details.

Comment: If secondary SP accesses some table then provide CREATE TABE for it and some sample data as INSERT INTO. We must have possibility to reproduce your issue (which is strange).